# everpad for evernote on ubuntu 15.10

Tags: evernote, ubuntu-15.10

I'm trying to install everpad on ubuntu 15.10 but there are no source available yet. Does anyone have an idea how to make it work?

If it's not compatible, we can make it compatible again together.

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution to install...

First install this:(http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/python-oauth2/python-oauth2_1.5.211-2ubuntu3_all.deb)

Then this: (http://ubuntu.cs.utah.edu/ubuntu/pool/universe/u/unity-singlet/python-unity-singlet_0.2.2-0ubuntu1_all.deb )

Finally you can install through the PPA (changing dists from wily to vivid in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nvbn-rm-ubuntu-ppa-wily.list).

I've got this from everpad's github issues/482